# Apply transparency on a WFS layer (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, layers, wfs, transparency-opacity

I'm trying to make a wfs layer transparent, but it gives me a mistake, but I can't solve it until now.

This is my code:

```
uri ='http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/rgis/datasets/6ca5428a-a78c-4c82-8120-da70dc92f2cc/services/ogc/wfs?SERVICE=wfs&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=tl_2010_35_state10'

wfslayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "MEXICO", "WFS")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(wfslayer)
```

*So far everything is correct*

```
 renderer = wfslayer.rendererV2()
```

*In this function it gives me the mistake*

I don't know if it's a problem with the version (QGIS 3.16.2) of the program or with the code.

It no longer lets me put the rest of the code.

```
symbol = renderer.symbol()
symbol.setAlpha(0.5)
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Hello Ian,  I have the error after put:    renderer = wfslayer.rendererV2(), then I can no longer continue with the function:   symbol = renderer.symbol()  and
symbol.setAlpha(0.5), to give transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually only need to add this line to your code after loading the WFS layer:

```
wfslayer.setOpacity(0.5) # enter opacity (transparency) value from 0-1
```

So overall, your code should be:

```
uri ='http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/rgis/datasets/6ca5428a-a78c-4c82-8120-da70dc92f2cc/services/ogc/wfs?SERVICE=wfs&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=tl_2010_35_state10'
wfslayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "MEXICO", "WFS")
wfslayer.setOpacity(0.5)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(wfslayer)
```

From the documentation: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.setOpacity

I suspect you were trying to implement an approach for the previous version of QGIS (2.X), but with QGIS 3.X onwards there are changes to the API for applying layer symbology.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  right, I was applying it like I was working on QGIS2, 
I will take into account ,as you comment, that the changes for the new current API
 with QGIS 3. Regards

Comment: Sure! Could you please mark the answer as accepted (green arrow)? So people will know that this solution has worked.

Comment: I'm sorry,
I can't find how to mark the answer as accepted, as you tell me

Comment: It's simply the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem, see here: 

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes! thanks, very easy